# calling web api with swift 4.1 (generic handler api )

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

Let me describe view controller (page) first. I have added one label and one button.

I try to call a web api with `swift 4.1.` in button click action. But it gives an error. Here is the error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1098d8b68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1098da288).
2018-05-23 10:35:34.217375+0300 apiSor2[1013:63745] Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1098d8b68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1098da288).
(lldb)
```

Here is the source code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var lblDetail: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = URL (string: "https://transsupp.com/testApp/ws17.ashx")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!)
    {
        (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController (title: "error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(okButton)

            self.present(alert, animated:true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            if (data != nil )
            {
                do
                {
                    let JSONResult = try
                        JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            print(JSONResult)
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }//if (data != nil ) ENDS
        } // if (error != nil) ENDS
    } //let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) ENDS
    task.resume()
} // btnClick ENDS

}
```

[as you see i try to call this api. Please click on it](https://transsupp.com/testApp/ws17.ashx)

Api returns this

```
[


{
    "resultCode": "999",
    "resultMessage": "ok",
    "showPopUpPage": "True",
    "contentTextOfPopUpPage": "ws01Settings4Colors.ashx<br/>table:renkAyarlari<br/>showPopUpPage:True<br/><a href=https://www.google.com>click for the link brother</a>and this a skip line in here<br/>it works or not work. lorem ipsum. lorem ipsum. lorem",
    "backgroundColor": "4D5656",
    "textColorOnThePage": "FFFFFF",
    "alertTextColorOnThePage": "E91E63",
    "buttonTextColor": "FFFFFF",
    "buttonBackgroundColor": "81D4FA",
    "alertButtonTextColor": "FFFFFF",
    "alertButtonBackgroundColor": "E91E63",
    "inputTextColor": "4D5656",
    "inputBackgroundColor": "FFFFFF",
    "dropDownMenuTextColor": "4D5656",
    "dropDownMenuBackgroundColor": "FFFFFF",
    "showBackgroundImage": "False",
    "backgroundImagePath": "http://transsupp.com/app/Assets/BackgroundImages/other_background.png"
  }
]
```

i try to get two json return: showBackgroundImage and backgroundColor to show them with label. How can i get these two json returns?

Comment: Your API returns an `Array` but you are casting it to `Dictionary`. That's why you are getting the error. Cast to `Array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error explains itself very well, you are casting an array to a dictionary.

`[]` in JSON means an array, or list of values. you are trying to use a single one.

This line:

```
let JSONResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
```

should be

```
let JSONResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String: Any]]
```

**Note:** For Swift 4 and above, dont use JSONSerlialization. use Codable

**Note 2:** Don't use force unwrap i.e (`data!`). if it is nil it will crash your app. Use `if let` or `guard`

**Basic Parsing**

```
for row in jsonResult {
    if let backgroundColor = row["backgroundColor"] as? String {
         self.color = backgroundColor 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I see whole json result in output window in xcode. Now i need to parse this return, right? To get 'showBackgroundImage' and 'backgroundColor' items ?

Comment: I will add a snippet to my answer to help, but you should use codable.. which would make it alot easier. Updated

Answer (score 0):

The error shows your result is an array but you casted it to a dictionary. According to the api you gave. It returns an array and its first element is the dictionary you want.